# How do you format code on save in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I would like to automatically format TypeScript code using the build-in formatter when I save a file in Visual Studio Code.

I'm aware of the following options, but none of them is good enough:

- Format manually `Shift + Alt + F`
- Format on type `"editor.formatOnType": true`

  - It formats the line when you press enter. Unfortunatelly, it leaves it unformatted when you mouse-click another line or press up/down arrow.
- Use existing extension

  - I tried this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gyuha.format-on-save), but it does not seem to work too well.
- Use beautify `"beautify.onSave": true`

  - It does not work with TypeScript
- Write custom extension

  - It's tricky if you want to handle autosaves and builds correctly.

Comment: If you have the prettier extension installed. On windows press Alt + Shift + f or search @id:editor.defaultFormatter in the settings and choose prettier as the default formatter.

Answer (score 633, accepted):

As of September 2016 (VSCode 1.6), this is now officially [supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_6#_format-on-save).

Add the following to your **`settings.json`** file:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

Here is the menu to access the settings
[image]

Comment: is there a way to exclude some files? i.e I want to only format .js files not .html files.

Comment: @gabodev77prettier in VS Code has options for this (e.g. prettier.javascriptEnable, prettier.cssEnable...) though not for HTML.

Comment: Can it format on Autosave?  formatOnSave is working for me only when I manually hit Cmd+S.

Comment: @gabrielAnzaldo See this question for how to exclude certain files / file types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-files-from-format-on-save-in-vscode/44831631

Comment: @LukeWilliams This is currently not possible, there's a feature request for it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45997

Comment: I don't want it too format on Autosave anymore actually (2 years later)... setting up cmd+s as well as format-on-commit (with Husky and lint-staged) works perfectly and ensures that nothing unformatted gets checked in.  Thanks for the info though @Gama11!

Comment: Personally I do want the format on autosave - a shame the issue got closed by a bot without a satisfactory explanation :-(

Comment: To have this only work for C#:
      "[csharp]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
      },

Comment: Don't forget to "Cmd+Shift+P" and "reload window" to apply the changes

Answer (score 210):

No need to add commands anymore. For those who are new to Visual Studio Code and searching for an easy way to format code on saving, kindly follow the below steps.

1. Open Settings by pressing `[Cmd+,]` in Mac (or `[Ctrl+,]` in Windows/Linux) or using the below screenshot.

[image: VS Code - Open Settings Command Image]

2. Type '**format**' in the search box and enable the option '**Format On Save**'.

[image]

You are done. Thank you.

Answer (score 102):

If you would like to auto format on save just with Javascript source, add this one into `Users Setting` (press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then type `Open Settings (JSON)` to open `settings.json` file)

```
"[javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }
```

Comment: my version, i started searching "formatOnSave" and just had to click a checkbox in the Vs Code Settings UI

Comment: For multiple languages, this syntax works: `"[rust][javascript]": { ... }`

Answer (score 28):

For **eslint**:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.eslint": true }
```

Answer (score 20):

For neet formatting for any language you can use `Prettier - code formatter`.
After applying this you can format code **Alt + Shift + f**
[image]

Answer (score 12):

The best to avoid conflicts is defining individual formatters for each language, for instance if I am working with **Rust** and **Typescript** I would like to format code using the extensions **Rust-Analyzer** and **Prettier** respectively, therefore on my **.vscode/settings.json**:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

Remember that both Prettier and rust-analyzer extensions must be installed first.

Answer (score 8):

If you use **Prettier** and this line

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Doesn't work to format on save, you might need to add another command to **settings.json**

`"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`,

Comment: thank you, "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode", helped me

Answer (score 6):

For **MAC** user, 
add this line into your Default Settings

File path is: /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

"tslint.autoFixOnSave": true

Sample of the file would be:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "typescript.check.tscVersion": false,
    "vsicons.projectDetection.disableDetect": true,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "tslint.autoFixOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After hours of struggle... below steps worked.
Full details below.

1. **Install** this extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save

2. **Add** below json, to below file:

**File:**

```
<your-project-directory>\.vscode\settings.json
    OR
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
```

**JSON:**

NOTE: Make sure commas before and after below block.

```json
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
    "runOnSave.statusMessageTimeout": 3000,
    "runOnSave.commands": [
        {
            "match": ".*\\.*",
            "command": "editor.action.formatDocument",
            "runIn": "vscode"
        }
    ],
```

Now, when the code is changed, after 1 second, it gets formatted & saved automatically.

Comment: This actually worked quite well. To make this even better you can install [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) so formatting becomes cleaner instead of the default vs code formatter. I also changed the `runOnSave.statusMessageTimeout` to a bit more so it doesn't just interrupt your coding flow and formats it.

Comment: I meant `autoSaveDelay` instead of `statusMessageTimeout `, mb

Comment: Fun with vscode, after installing the extension and adding the two `runonsave` entries in setting, the autosave does not work anymore. But the autoformat works. Wait, it works, I had the delay with a high value, so plus one, although you should have been more detailed regarding the two key descriptions of `runonsave`

Answer (score 5):

For me `formatOnSave` wasn't working because I had prettier installed and hadn't yet chosen between the built-in and prettier as my default formatter.

To trigger the selection dialog I had to press `Alt + Shift + f` on my json file.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to choose the formatter which you have just added as an extension.
Press **ctrl + alt + f** and choose the formatter that you want from the dropdown.
Post that with every save it will get automatically formatted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling setting `Format On Save`, for python developers, you may need to install **autopep8** package which is used by **vscode** as default to format the python code when the code is saved.

```
pip install autopep8
```

and then, press `ctrl + s` to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Goto settings and search format 
`check Editor: Format On Save`

or follow these steps

[image: Update your settings]