# How can I reindent code on saved in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I have `Beautify` installed and enabled.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

I tested on my a php file,

[image]

When I hit save, I can't get the reindent or beautify to happen.

What did I missed ?

## Code > User > settings.json

```
{
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 11,
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
  // syncedSideBar
  "explorer.autoReveal": true,
  // Is git enabled
  "git.enabled": false,
  // Path to the git executable
  "git.path": null,
  // Whether auto fetching is enabled.
  "git.autofetch": false,
  "workbench.statusBar.visible": false,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "openInGitHub.providerType": "github",
  "gitlens.advanced.messages": {
    "suppressGitDisabledWarning": true
  },
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "window.closeWhenEmpty": false,
  "editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false,
  "editor.dragAndDrop": false,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro",
  "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
  "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": true,
  "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false,
  "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 5,
  "window.title": "${activeEditorFull}${separator}${rootName}",
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "editor.useTabStops": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.formatOnType": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

I just want to reindent my code when I saved.

Comment: isn't this for javascript? why you are using it for PHP why not using prettier for PHP: https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php

Answer (score 4):

From the Beautify extension repo [README](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify):

> Beautify `javascript`, `JSON`, `CSS`, `Sass`, and `HTML` in Visual Studio Code.

You are attempting to format PHP code.

I recommend [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client). It formatted my file well on save.

[image: PHP Intelephense extension]

Before save:

[image: PHP code unformatted]

After save:

[image: PHP code formatted]

**IMPORTANT:** only formats a file if it contains no closing `?>` php tag. You will have to remove your closing tags. From [PHP Tags documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue is already listed on [Beautify official github repository](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify)

As per their reponse

> Beautify doesn't support PHP.
>
> If you want beautify `PHP` files, you have to use different addon,
>   for example:

[phpfmt - PHP formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows click on 'File' -> Preferences -> Settings. Then search for editor.formatOnSave, and put "true" instead of "false"

For Mac click on 'Code' (top left of screen, to the left of 'File', 'Edit', and 'View') -> Preferences -> Settings -> enter the term 'editor.formatOnSave' in the search settings box at the top of the page. Click on the tick to mark it as true.

src: [Beautify on save in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771855/beautify-on-save-in-vs-code)

Comment: `"editor.formatOnSave": true` is already there, you'll see it if you look at the question `settings.json` source.