# How to turn off auto formatting in visual studio code Version: 1.35.1 (system setup)

Tags: html, node.js, visual-studio-code, mustache

I am using visual studio code for my Node JS application with mustache templating. I have below code in one of my html files :

```
<script>
 {{{interface}}}
</script>
```

Due to auto formatting on save, it turns out to be a below (space added between braces):

```
<script>
     { { { interface } } }
  </script>
```

This is giving below error on browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: interface is not defined
```

I have tried to set editor.formatOnSave to false but could not find this switch.

Below is my version info on VS Code:

```
Version: 1.35.1 (system setup)
Commit: c7d83e57cd18f90026a8162d042843yui1bcf27m
Date: 2019-06-12T15:16:14.389Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT ia32 10.0.17134
```

How to get rid of this auto format feature on save?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a setting for that option. See picture below.

Note that VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:

- **User Settings** - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
- **Workspace Settings** - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.

Also please see the `Edit in settings.json` settings at the end of the screen. If you switch to older view you can manually edit the settings file. 
[See answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494277/how-do-you-format-code-on-save-in-vs-code)

[image: format on save settings]