# How to remove the Insert ; errors in react-native followed by prettier prettier

Tags: react-native, eslint, prettier, react-native-web, eslintrc

Trying to fix the error since long , not able to figure it out why I am getting errors due to some
prettier/prettier thing which keeps on saying that 'Insert ;' / 'Insert enter' in my react-native project.

Also showing error in App.js
ERROR:
Line 1:9 : Replace `View,.Text` with `.View, .Text.`    prettier/prettier

Here is my .eslintrc.js file :

```
module.exports = {
    root:true,
    extends:'@react-native-community'
}
```

Here is my prettier.js file :

```
module.exports = {
    arrowParens:'avoid',
    bracketSameLine:true,
    bracketSpacing:false,
    singleQuote:true,
    trailingComma: 'all',
}
```

App.js first line

```
import {View , Text} from 'react-native'
```

I have installed the need eslint and other packages but it didn't solved.Also I don't have any VScode extensions related to them installed.
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to installing prettier - code formatter . and also try to enable format on save [How do you format code on save in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494277/how-do-you-format-code-on-save-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer after searching a lot!

Change eslintrc.js a bit as below:

module.exports = {
root:true,
extends:'@react-native-community'
rules:{
'prettier/prettier':0
}
}

That would solve the issue!