# How can I make VS Code format my Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have following Python code:

```
check_files(original_file = original_file_name, 
                   used_file = used_file_name, 
                   unused_file = unused_file_name)
```

I want to make it instead to look like:

```
check_files(original_file = original_file_name, 
            used_file = used_file_name, 
            unused_file = unused_file_name)
```

Also I want to correct formatting not only for function calls but also that way dictionary key/value pairs and etc.

For Example, in RStudio, if I select the code and press <kbd>CTRL + I</kbd> RStudio will correct formating as I have described above. Is there any similar way to correct formating in VSCode?

Comment: what Python formatter are you using? or are you using none?

Comment: @starball what you mean by formatter? Can you please give me examples?

Comment: see the possible values of the `editor.defaultFormatter` setting / google "python code formatters".

Comment: @starball Thank you. For `editor.defaultFormatter` I have `None`. Should I select one for Python? It will autoiddent or I need to force it with hotkey?

Comment: See [format code on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494277/how-do-you-format-code-on-save-in-vs-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments by @starball, @jarmod and additional googling I found that you need to follow those steps:

**Step 1.** Install `Python` extension from marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

**Step 2.** Install one of the formatter packages for Python.

> The Python extension supports source code formatting using either
> autopep8 (the default), black, or yapf.

from and More about it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting

**Step 3.** Select which code formatter you want to use in `python.formatting.provider` which is in `settings>Extensions>Python` (this maybe automatically set after step 1 and step 2). Also, in `settings>Extensions>Python` there are more options to select.

**How to use formatting:**

The code formatting is available in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) through the following shortcuts or key combinations:

On Windows <kbd>Shift + Alt + F</kbd>

On macOS <kbd>Shift + Option + F</kbd>

On Linux <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd>

Format Selection (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>) - Format the selected text.

Or you can use right click menu:

[image]

from: https://mkyong.com/vscode/how-to-format-source-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode/

and from: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting