# How to auto-format clojure "on save" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure, vscode-calva

I'm currently using VSCode, and I'm trying to auto-format clojure files. I have Calva installed.

I've typed the following code into my `.clj` file:

```
(let [a    :b]
(str "foo"     "bar" "baz"
"a"    a))
```

I'm expecting it to auto format when I save, but it's not working for some reason. Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: get a VS Code extension that contributes formatting for clojure, and then follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494277/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension such as: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marcomorain.clojure-lint that works with `clj-kondo`.

Additionally, you can add an alias in your `project.clj` to lint with `clj-kondo`. See the docs: https://github.com/clj-kondo/clj-kondo.