# auto format on js and jsx in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

How can I turn my code on save

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h2>{counter}</h2>
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick} type="button" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
      >
        increase
      </button>
    </div>
  )
```

into this format in vscode
I use prettier but it didnt work.

```
return (
    <div>
      <h2>{counter}</h2>
      <button
        className="btn"
        onClick={handleClick}
        type="button"
        style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
      >
        increase
      </button>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: You'll probably need to configure Prettier or you use another extension with Prettier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39494277/17724435, refer this SO question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with prettier. Go to the prettier extension settings and look for the "Single Attribute Per Line" setting and make sure that it is enabled. By default, it is turned off.