Code changes when I save the file in visual studio code
Today, when I tried to save my file, the code was completely scrambled. I've been using this file for a couple weeks now and this has never happened before. Does anyone know what's going on here?
Here's the before:

Here's the after:

And it's not just the look, but also the code. It's full of errors.
I've also added code chunks:
BEFORE:
    async function listEmails() {
            let response;
            try {
                response = await gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
                    'userId': 'me',
                });
            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
                return;
            }
            const emails = response.result.messages;
            if (!emails || emails.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No emails found.';
                console.log('No emails found.');
                return;
            }
            // Flatten to string to display
            const output = emails.reduce(
                (str, email) => `${str}${email.name}\n`,
                'Emails:\n');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
        }

AFTER:
    async f        Emails() {
            let response;
            try {
            response = await gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
                'userId': 'm                            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById                t = err.message;             ret             }
                     = response.result.messages;
            if (!emails || email            
               um        ntById('content').innerText = 'No emails                      console.log('No emails f                     return;
            }
            // Flatten to string to                 const output = emails.reduce(             (str, e        st        me}\n`,
                'Emails:              document.getElementById(            Text = output;
        }


Please ensure that the code is posted in text format, and not as a screenshot.

@toyotaSupra you can only understand the problem in the current posted form.

perhaps you have an extension that doesn't work quite properly? Try cmd+shift+p and do Save without formatting. If that saves the file without scrambling the content, you can check here to see how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494277/how-do-you-format-code-on-save-in-vs-code

Have you made any changes to your VSCode settings recently? Also, have you made any upgrades to the VSCode application?

@ChukwujiobiCanon My screen reader reads Here's the before:  image of clean code. Here's the after:  an image of messy, confusing code code. Perhaps you can "only understand the problem in the current posted form", but those of us who can't see the images can't...

@ChukwujiobiCanon Since the last time that I've used it (last week) I have no made any changes or added any extensions. I added a few php ones they didn't create this error when I used it last week...

I’m so sorry about that @HereticMonkey. The image visual complements the post that’s all. The post can still be summarized without the images.

Added code chunks.

@Aᴍɪʀ I tried this and it didn't scramble the content. However, I very much like the formatted code - how do I maintain it somehow?

This is either the result of a poorly executed extension, perhaps recently updated even though not recently installed; or, the result of a corruption. You may have corrupted hardware, a corrupted file due to saving under less than ideal conditions, or downloaded a corrupted copy from online. I would suggest turning off all extensions, running a defrag on your hard drive, moving the target fold to somewhere else temporarily, or even to a separate thumb drive, and manually inspecting the save file to look for errors with a text editor.

@PriyaPatel - If what Amir said was true, and that linked question is related, then it would imply using "[php][javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true } should help as it seems you may be using multiple languages which could confuse the formatter.

This question is similar to: How do you format code on save in VS Code. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try installing the prettier extension, while disabling other formatting extensions, then try again.

@TravisJ I'm able to avoid scrambling my code if I turn off the code formatter, but that doesn't solve the problem. I don't have any extensions on that "beautify' my code, so it's not clear what's causing it. Where do I paste this line of code: "[php][javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }

I can confirm that even after disabling all my extensions and restarting, the problem still exists. The code is still scrambled on save if Format on Save is toggled.

If that is the case let me suggest you uninstall VS Code cleanly, then reinstall a fresh copy.

I solved the problem by going into my settings.json, which looked like this:
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/priyapatel/anaconda3/bin/python",
  "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
  "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable",
  "liveServer.settings.showOnStatusbar": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  }
}

And I got rid of the last line, so that the document now looks like this:
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/priyapatel/anaconda3/bin/python",
  "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
  "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable",
  "liveServer.settings.showOnStatusbar": true
}

Solved the problem for me.

I think the actual reason is that the formatter is set to the wrong one.

Can you clarify what you mean?

The formatter is set to the HTML one, but you're using it to format JS code. That may be the reason that the code is all messed up.
